# iOS 7 upgrade makes annotation call out accessories stay open after clicked

Tags: ios, mapkit, ios7, mkannotation, mkannotationview

With the new iOS 7 update, my custom annotation call out accessories stay open forever unless I restart the app, or refresh the annotations. For example, if a user pick's a location in New York and returns to the map to continue their search after viewing the location, the New York location's call out accessory would remain open until I restart the app. It becomes an issue when multiple locations have been viewed because numerous call outs are open on the map. My question is 1, how can I prevent this from happening? And 2, why do the annotation call outs stay open now that iOS 7 has been introduced, this was never an issue before? Thanks for your time with this, any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:     (id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
MKAnnotationView *vw = [[MKAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"boardwalk"];

Annotation *myant = (Annotation *)annotation;

//show custom annotation for user loc
if (annotation == mapView.userLocation) 
{
    [mapView.userLocation setTitle:@"I am here!"];
    NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    NSString *userLocDisplay = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@ Lat: %@ / Lon: %@", latitude, longitude];
    [mapView.userLocation setSubtitle:userLocDisplay];
    return nil;
} 
else if([myant.typeIdentifier isEqualToString:@"park"]) 
{ 
    vw.image =[UIImage imageNamed: @"prkmarker.png"];
}


    //set up annotation view
    vw.enabled = YES;
    vw.canShowCallout = YES;

    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]
                   initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"GTAIcon.png"]];
    vw.leftCalloutAccessoryView = imgView;
    vw.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

    return vw;
}
```

Comment: can you post the code?

Comment: are you implement setSelected: method?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I updated the comment with the code.

Answer (score 1):

Implement this delegate method,

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    [view.leftCalloutAccessoryView removeFromSuperview];
    [view.rightCalloutAccessoryView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: I was finally able to test this method in my app and it did not work. I appreciate the effort but I am still searching for the solution.

Comment: Now I have a MKMapView that has a number of annotations. Selecting the pin displays the callout and pressing the accessory pops a new view controller onto the stack. However when I press back from the new VC, the callout accessory remains open. How do I close it?

Comment: Remove the callout in viewWillAppear